# Add item to Jenkins sidepanel

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I'm developing a Jenkins plugin where I'm trying to add a link with an icon to the sidepanel under Manage Jenkins->Manage Nodes. My link would be placed just below "New Node".

I've implemented a simple Action, but what should I do with it to make it appear in the sidepanel?

```
public class BuildCountAction implements Action {

    public BuildCountAction() {}

    public String getIconFileName() {
        return "clipboard.gif";
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Test";
    }

    public String getUrlName() {
        return "testurl";
    }
}
```

Comment: just wondering if you ever figured out how to solve this problem? Ive been struggling for awhile with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at similar plugins that already exist for Hudson/Jenkins..

- [Hudson Sidebar Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sidebar-Link+Plugin)
- [Jenkins Sidebar Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin)